# Can I view tasks that will be run by ansible-playbook?

Tags: ansible

Can I review tasks that would be run by ansible-playbook?

`ansible-playbook --check` does not list all tasks.  Tasks which [depend on previous tasks being performed may fail](http://blog.nordeus.com/dev-ops/ansible-check-mode-tips.htm), causing ansible to stop half-way through.

`ansible-playbook --list-tasks` does not respect --limit, or when the provided inventory omits a host.  So it lists too many tasks.

```
$ rpm -q ansible
ansible-2.2.0.0-3.fc25.noarch
```

---

Another puzzle here is the apparent duplication in output of --list-tasks, which can also be seen in --list-hosts.  In the example below, the only host in the inventory is alan-laptop.  I don't see why the target hosts frpm the playbook are being listed twice on the first line - first with brackets, and then without.

```
  play #1 (all): all    TAGS: []
    pattern: [u'all']
    hosts (1):
      alan-laptop

  play #2 (alan-laptop, alan-nuc): alan-laptop, alan-nuc    TAGS: []
    pattern: [u'alan-laptop, alan-nuc']
    hosts (1):
      alan-laptop
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you're unhappy with --check mode, it is possible to solve the problem with --list-tasks.  Follow the recommended "[content organisation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html#top-level-playbooks-are-separated-by-role)", and keep separate playbooks for groups of hosts which require the same tasks.